# Bash pipeline's exit status differs in script

Tags: bash, pipe, exit, exit-status

The following bash pipeline returns 1:

```
$ false | true
$ echo $?
1
```

However it returns 0 when executed in an script:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
false | true
echo $?

$ bash test.sh
0
```

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Run `set -o | grep pipefail` in an interactive shell and in a script.

Comment: N.B. - The bash `true` "command" returns **zero** for its exit code, and `false` returns **one**.  This corresponds to *"no errors" = SUCCESS* in shell programming, as opposed to **boolean false** = zero and **boolean true** = not false (i.e., *any non-zero number*) in most programming languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard behavior for bash is to return exit status of the last command in the pipeline, as in your script. It looks that you have enabled **pipefail** option in the interactive shell which forces the return of the last command with non-zero exit status. Here is how it works:

```
$ set -o pipefail    # enable pipefail
$ false | true
$ echo $?
1

$ set +o pipefail    # disable pipefail
$ false | true
$ echo $?
0
```